# React - Pass JSX / React component to "unrelated" component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, mobx, mobx-react-lite

I'm looking for a flexible approach that will allow me to send some JSX to a totally unrelated component. For example, a modal.

Let's assume we have some boilerplate code for a global store and we can access it from any component with a custom `useStore` hook. So a very barebones modal could look like this:

```js
// Modal.jsx
function Modal() {
  const store = useStore()

  if(!store.modal.isVisible) return null

  return <div>{store.modal.content}</div>
}
```

Now, if I just want to display some text, that works perfectly fine. And even though JSX shouldn't belong in the store, it kind of works when `store.modal.content` is a react component. However, it breaks when using hooks. The following would be an ideal solution syntax-wise, but doesn't work with mobx as the store. And like I said, I don't want to risk some strange behaviour by putting JSX or a `useRef()` reference in the store.

```js
function ToggleThing() {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false)

  return <button onClick={() => setActive(!isActive)}>{isActive.toString()}</button>
}


function SomeModalTrigger() {
  const store = useStore();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() =>
       store.setModalContent(<ToggleThing />) // <-- This would be perfect
      }
    >
      Trigger Modal
    </button>
  );
}
```

---

### Non-ideal solutions

The content needs to be truly dynamic, so a solution to just save a string and maybe some props in the store and use an object as a component lookup wouldn't work.

```js
const modalComponents = {
  someComponent,
  anotherComponent
}
// -> modalComponents[store.modal.component]
```

Also, I'd like to avoid some dangling variable that stores the JSX and is not part of a store/hook/component. Even though this would work it makes maintenance difficult and breaks the core concept of react

```js
let modalContent = null // Not in a component

function Modal() {
  const store = useStore()

  return <div>{modalContent}</div> 
  // If modalContent is updated without triggering a component rerender, the content becomes stale
}

function SomeModalTrigger() {
  const store = useStore();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        modalContent = <ToggleThing />;
        store.triggerModalUpdate();
      }}
    >
      Trigger Modal
    </button>
  );
}
```

Note: The actual code is much more complex than that and not really about modals, so it's not as easy as using a modal package. Modals were just the most approachable way to describe the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; it's not ideal to put JSX elements into store-like places because they're not serializable.

One way to achieve this is to use [createPortal](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react-dom/createPortal#reference), which allows you to portal/render a JSX element (component) under a specific DOM node.

If you only need to display one modal at a time, you can give the modal-container a unique and fixed `id` and retrieve the DOM node using `document.getElementById` in `SomeModalTrigger`, as demonstrated in the official documentation.

If you need to display multiple modals at the same time, you may need to give each modal a dynamic `id` (which you can generate using the new `useId` hook), and store this id(s) in the store so that it's accessible to `SomeModalTrigger`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about portals too, but I was a bit hesitant in the hopes of finding a clever solution that doesn‘t rely on handling the elements with HTML IDs. Since this can also create a discrepancy between IDs in the store and actual DOM elements. I feel like that‘s the best middle-ground for now though. I‘ll leave the question open for a bit more and accept yours if no alternative comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about stores but you can use the context api. Take a look below.

Note that we wrap the component in a anonymous function even though it itself is a function. That's because useState and setState allow us to pass a callback that takes the previous state.  `setCounter(prev => prev + 1)`

So when it finds a function it assumes it's that callback and invokes it. So to avoid it calling our createElement functions, we pass our own callback that returns the component.

```js
const { useContext, useState, createContext } = React

const ModalContext = createContext();

// Sample modal bodies
const H1 = ({name}) => <h1>{name}</h1>
const H2 = ({name}) => <h2>{name}</h2>

const App = () => {
  const [Modal, setModal] = useState(() => H1);
  const [modalProps, setModalProps] = useState({name: 'Foo'});
  const modalContext = {Modal, setModal, modalProps, setModalProps}
  
  return (
  <div>
    <ModalContext.Provider value={modalContext}>
      <Page />
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  </div>
  )
}

const ModalWrapper = () => {
  const {Modal, modalProps} = useContext(ModalContext)
  return (
  <div>
    <Modal {...modalProps} />
  </div>
   )
}

const Page = () => {
  const {setModal, setModalProps} = useContext(ModalContext);
  function setH1() {
    setModal(() => H1);
    setModalProps({name: 'Foo'})
  }
  function setH2() {
    setModal(() => H2)
    setModalProps({name: 'Bar'})
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setH1}>Set H1</button>
      <button onClick={setH2}>Set H2</button>
      <ModalWrapper />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, app)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```